# Guava's CharMatcher removeFrom

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, jvm, guava

There are two questions here actually. The first one:

*1) Is Java smart enough not to copy one array element into itself?*

What I mean by that is :

```
 int i = 1;
 char [] chars=... //some chars
 char[1] = char[i]; // first element into itself
```

*2) Are the benchmarking's that guava made available to the public?*

And what I mean by that is: I was looking into the source code of CharMatcher removeFrom method and saw this :

```
        // This unusual loop comes from extensive benchmarking
    OUT: while (true) {
            pos++;
            while (true) {
                if (pos == chars.length) {
                    break OUT;
                }
                if (isLetter(chars[pos])) {
                    break;
                }
                chars[pos - spread] = chars[pos];
                pos++;
            }
            spread++;
        }
    return new String(chars, 0, pos - spread);
```

I really liked the idea, but coded my own method:

```
    public static String removeMine(String input){
    char [] chars = input.toCharArray();
    int howManyLetters = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<chars.length;++i){
        if(isLetter(chars[i])) {
            chars[howManyLetters++] = chars[i];
        }
        else {
            if(i == (chars.length - 1)) break;
            chars[i] = chars[i+1];
        }
    }
    return new String(chars, 0, howManyLetters);
}
```

I then added some benchmarks (I will put them on github if needed), here are the results:

https://microbenchmarks.appspot.com/runs/61e76bdc-b0d6-4145-8b8b-c1683287f038#r:scenario.benchmarkSpec.parameters.input,scenario.benchmarkSpec.methodName

I have (serious?) doubts that creators of guava did not have a version like that and I assume there was a strong reason to drop it (the comment is more then obvious). What I would like to see is either the actual benchmarks that they made or some serious reason to have such a method. I assume it has to do with the type of JVM that you run your code into, but actual proof would be appreciated.

P.S. I am still to test this with jmh also, will provide results once I'm done.

Comment: For the first question, I suppose checking if both indexes are same and then deciding whether to copy or not takes longer than simply to copy.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann of course, every branches introduces some small delay.